# Formulário com Node/EJS não funciona!

Tags: node.js, ejs

Bom dia pessoal, estou fazendo um formulário, utilizando Node e a view engine EJS, no entanto estou com problema para pegar dados dos formulários na controller. O retorno do req.body sempre é undefined.

app.js com body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Formulário .EJS

```
<form method='post' action='/save' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <label> Paciente </label> <br />
    <input type='text' name='patient' value='oi' /> <br />

    <label> Imagem: </label> <br />
    <input type='file' id='image' name='image' /> <br />

    <label>Descrição: </label> <br />
    <textarea id='description' name='description' rows=3></textarea> <br />

    <button type='submit'> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

Controller, com método post:

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.patient);
  console.log(req.body.description);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`bodyParser` não suporta `multipart/form-data`, uma alternativa pode ser usar o [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Exemplo:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) // dest = destino onde ficara o arquivo

var app = express()

app.post('/save', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file é o aquivo `image`
  // req.body terá os campos textos, se tiver algum 
})
```